# Bundle additional apps (built by myself) in one app?

Tags: java, android

I have built a launcher for people with bad eyesight, I have 3 additional apps made specifically for universal access: a calculator, a weather app and a music player.

To include them in my launcher I could simly copy their codes inside my launcher package and use an intent to open them (they would basically be different activities of the same app) but the problem is that my launcher is already built to launch regular apps (like every launcher does) and I don't want to mess up the code adding icons with a different behavior.

A couple of times I've downloaded an app in android and ended up with more apps that I wanted most of the time these ones containing some sort of spam. So while this is an annoying use of the feature it shows this is possible. But I have not come across this for a while, so I'm wondering if it's still possible.

How can I bundle my apps in the same app download? Is it still possible? How is this case scenario currently handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so basically you need to have multiple launcher categories in your manifest, for activity that you need to see on launcher.

E.g

```
 <activity android:name=".activities.A" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activities.B" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Can they reference different packages? Like .calc.MainActivity, .player.MainActivity? That's what I'm trying and I'm hardly getting nowhere. I got the calc to work but the player doesn't

Comment: yea you should try to give the complete package name. com.abc.calc.MainActivity