# Bundle mobile apps into single download

Tags: android, ios, mobile

Is it possible to bundle several mobile apps into a single download? So a person can install the bundled apps, then have several new apps available on their phone.

For example, a bundle of iOS apps, or a bundle of Android apps?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164068/bundle-additional-apps-built-by-myself-in-one-app/14164508#14164508

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iOS you can't do it. I tried to place multiple application in one ipa (which is just zip), but it will recognized just one of them.

Downloading additional content is also prohibited on iOS.

However, if you distribute application over the air, you can create a file (I don't remember exactly how it's called) which will have multiple asset's in it (multiple ipa's).

For Android, pablisco and user2115660 pretty much covered it.

Comment: Thanks Victor, combined with the response from pablisco this sums it up pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that as it is. What wou can do is add an extra Activity with a CATEGORY_HOME in the intent filter and it will appear as a separate app on Android's launcher:

```
<intent-filter>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
</intent-filter>
```

You would have to change the icon and label properties of the activity for it to have a different icon and name as well :)

**UPDATE:**

The format I was using for the intent filter wasn't correct. This is how the activities would have to be declared inside the application tag in the manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" 
    android:icon="@drawable/main_icon"  
    android:label="@string/main_app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".SecondaryActivity" 
    android:icon="@drawable/secondary_icon" 
    android:label="@string/secondary_app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

If you want to include an Activity inside a library project you will have include the full path to that given Activity.

One interesting approach would be to create both apps like library projects and then compound them into one. Bear in mind that you can't package library projects into apk so you would have to do separate projects if you want to create individual products.

Here is some info about library projects: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html

Comment: Thanks pablisco, do you have any examples of packaging apps like this?

Answer (score 0):

I saw one app that after instillation started downloading apk's and installing them.

Comment: Nir, do you remember what app that was?

Answer (score 0):

For iOS, outside of the jailbreak world, of which I am not overly familiar with, no.